# Checkbox onchange function does not firing when force check checkbox from javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input type password to enter password, and there is a show password checkbox to change the input type password to text, so the input password character is visible. There is also random password button to randomize the password and check the checkbox to show the password when the button clicked.

The problem is when clicking the random password button to fire JavaScript code to check the show password checkbox , the `onchange` checkbox function doesn't triggered/running. here's my code

```js
    function togglePassword(checkbox) {
        var x = document.getElementById("staff-password");
        if (checkbox.checked == true){
          x.type = "text";
        } else {
          x.type = "password";
        }
    }
    
    function clickRandom(){ 
      var randomPass = randomPass();
      document.getElementById("staff-password").value(randomPass);
      document.getElementById("show-password").checked = true;
    }
    
    function randomPass() {
      var length = 6;
      var text = "";
      var possible = "3907154628";
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      }
      return text;
    }
```

```html
    <span> Password </span>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="staff-password" maxlength="6" value="">
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="togglePassword(this)" id="show-password" >
    <span style="margin-left:3px;">Show Password</span>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" id="random-password" onclick="clickRandom()">
      <span>Random password</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Where is the script tag in HTML file. Try putting it at the end. And wrap you JavaScript in function ready(){your code goes here}

Comment: Try using === in the togglePassword if

Comment: In that case, you could just call togglePassword in clickRandom() :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct that dynamic updates to the state of a form field don't cause the typical events that are raised from a user's interaction. Instead, you can just manually call the callback yourself.

See comments inline

```js
function togglePassword(checkbox) {
        var x = document.getElementById("staff-password");
        if (checkbox.checked == true){
          x.type = "text";
        } else {
          x.type = "password";
        }
    }
    
    function clickRandom(){ 
      // value is a property, you have to assign it a value:
      document.getElementById("staff-password").value = randomPass();
      document.getElementById("show-password").checked = true;
      togglePassword(document.getElementById("show-password")); // Manually call the toggle function
    }
    
    function randomPass() {
      var length = 6;
      var text = "";
      var possible = "3907154628";
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      }
      return text;
    }
```

```html
<span> Password </span>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="staff-password" maxlength="6" value="">
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="togglePassword(this)" id="show-password" >
    <span style="margin-left:3px;">Show Password</span>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" id="random-password" onclick="clickRandom()">
      <span>Random password</span>
    </button>
```